# php loop posts with 2 categories

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, wordpress-theming

I am building a WordPress theme for my personal website portfolio. I'm still learning as I go, with php.

I'm looping posts and displaying their thumbnails and titles on my category archive pages. I would like to show posts of a specific category first, so I gave them a category of 'special', besides their original category/ies.

**The way I though of doing this was:

· If -> the category has posts that also have the category 'special': display those;

· After that -> display the posts from the original category that haven't been displayed yet.**

My first attempt looped all the posts from the category 'special', and then loop again the category in question. But this displays all the posts from the category 'special', wether or not they have the category of that archive page, and then displays the posts from the original category, even if they are already displayed.

```
<div class="projects-container">

    <!-- Loop projects from the category 'Special' -->

    <?php
        $args = array( 'category_name'  => 'Special', );
        $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    ?>

    <?php if ( $query -> have_posts() ) : ?>
        <?php while ( $query -> have_posts() : $query -> the_post(); ?>

            <!-- the content -->

        <?php endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
    endif; ?>

    <!-- Loop projects from the main category -->

    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <!-- the content -->

        <?php endwhile;
    endif; ?>

</div>
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: These are normal posts, we are not talking about any custom post type, right? Then you should probably rather not do this by introducing such a "special" category. WP has a mechanism for "sticky posts" already, https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/sticky-posts/ Those get automatically sorted to the top, if the query does not have `ignore_sticky_posts` set.

Comment: _"But this displays all the posts from the category 'special', wether or not they have the category of that archive page"_ - of course it does, because that category is the _only_ selection criterion you have provided here. You are not using the WP main query here (which on a category archive page, will _already_ filter the posts by that category), you are making your own query, that is independent from everything else. You would have to determine what the category slug for the current archive page is, and then include that in your selection - `'category_name'  => 'xyz,Special'`

Comment: The sticky posts works great for this purpose, thank you @CBroe! I had tu use a plugin for it to apply also to the category pages, not only for the homepage, but that's ok.